# RestKit: how to POST objects using routes?

Tags: ios, restkit, restkit-0.20

The RKObjectManager [documentation](http://restkit.org/api/latest/Classes/RKObjectManager.html) shows how to construct this route

```
[manager.router.routeSet addRoute:[RKRoute routeWithName:@"follow_user" pathPattern:@"/users/:userID/follow" method:RKRequestMethodPOST]];
```

- I need to make the request first in order to set some headers.
- I need to give the object I want to post.
- I need to specify a dictionary containing the userID to be matched in the path pattern of the route

How do I make a url request to post an object using that route ?

EDIT:

requestWithPathForRouteNamed:object:parameters: does not let me give an object to post.
requestWithObject:method:path:parameters: does not let me give a dictionary dictionary containing the userID to be matched in the path pattern of the route

Actually I'd need something like :

```
- (NSMutableURLRequest *) requestWithObject:(id)objectToSend
                              forRouteNamed:(NSString *)routeName
                            routeParameters:(NSDictionary *)routeParameters;
```

Answer (score 1):

http://restkit.org/api/latest/Classes/RKObjectManager.html#//api/name/requestWithPathForRouteNamed:object:parameters:

Use the described API. You can set the headers using this API

http://brianflove.com/2012/09/27/setting-custom-http-request-headers-with-restkit/

Comment: this link refers to an article using an old, deprecated version of RestKit

Comment: Those docs are for the latest release version (just not the dev version) of RestKit. `requestWithPathForRouteNamed:object:parameters:` is the correct method. It has parameters for the `object` and the `parameters`. I don't see what your issue is @jafar

Comment: The brianlove article uses an old version of RestKit. Not the documentation indeed, sorry. The documentation says for that method "object:
The object with which to interpolate the path pattern of the named route. Can be nil." It's not the object to be sent right?

Comment: @Wain If I use "parameters:" to post an object then do I have to transform it into a dictionary myself or is there a way not to?